# Postgresql function syntax error, ";" is the problem

Tags: postgresql, function, syntax-error

I have problem with my Postgresql function. Is says that i have syntax error near ";" sign, but when i remove those which are causing the problem, Postgresql wants them back. Can someone explain to me what is wrong?

```
create procedure zwrot(iid int)
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
as $$
declare
ddostepnosc varchar(20);
ddataa date;
pieniadze int;
begin
select dostepnosc from samochod where id_samochod=iid into ddostepnosc;
select data_wystawienia from faktura  f inner join zakupy z on f.id_zakupy=z.id_zakupy inner join zakupy_has_samochod zhs
on zhs.id_zakupy=z.id_zakupy inner join samochod s on s.id_samochod=zhs.id_samochod where s.id_samochod=iid into ddataa;
    if(ddostepnosc!='dostepny') 
        then
        if(date_part('month',ddataa,current_date>= 3)
            then
                RAISE NOTICE 'Nie można zwrócic samochodu po ponad 3 miesiącach';
        else
                select cena_netto from zakupy_has_samochod zhs inner join samochod s on zhs.id_samochod=s.id_samochod where s.id_samochod=iid into pieniadze;
                select pieniadze*0.75 as pieniadze_zwrocone;
                update samochod set dostepnosc='dostepny' where id_samochod=iid;
        end if;
    else
        RAISE NOTICE 'Nie mozna zwrocic niesprzedanego samochodu';
    end if;
end;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `if` is missing a closing parenthesis.